# Use scalable bitmaps for seekbar/progressbar Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, seekbar

I am trying to create a custom look for the seekbar, and I created images for normal/filled and the thumb states. But the problem is that the images are not being scaled by android, instead are just tiled/clipped. How can I ask Android to scale the given images instead of tiling/clipping?

Comment: I just ran into same problem, I think this is a bug since the progress is scaled but not the background

Answer (score 1):

You can use java code to scale Bitmap images.

- Read bitmap as stream
- Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(your buffered in put stream);
- bm=bm.createScaledBitmap(bm,imgwidth,imgheight,new Boolean(false));

Comment: that is the last resort. But for other UI components, say a Button, if you assign a backgroundDrawable, it scales itself to fit the actual size. How to enable this in seekbar was my concern.

Comment: Yes you are correct, i never tried it in seekbar, so i thought may be this work around may work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ask Android to do this for you.

The images must be created in the size(s) you will be using them.